My physical disk has unaccessible free space
I tried double booting Asahi Linux to mess around with it, but regretted the partition size I choose. So, I tried changing it, but when I deleted the Volumes the free space left over does not show up on Disk Utility. I have tried partitioning disk0 through diskutil, but it tells me there is not enough space on the disk or a missing gap. I also tried erasing the disk and reinstalling macOS, but the free space is still there. It seems that for some reason diskutil and Disk Utility think my drive has no extra space on there despite the 95Gb of free space. I would like to just add the free space back to disk3. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

I would guess you added disk0s3 when you installed Asahi Linux. If so, then I think you could delete this partition (disk0s3) and add the free space to disk0s2 (disk3). The commands would be diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3 and diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0.

Thank you, and if you don't mind me asking, why did the EFI partition cause the issue? Before I deleted the 95gb volume, it showed up in disk utility while the EFI partition was still there. It only gave me problems when I deleted the volume and it became free space. Was the EFI partition using that free space somehow?

The Disk Utility hides EFI type partitions. This EFI partition disk0s3 physically occurred between the APFS container disk0s2 and the 95.9 GB of free space. This EFI partition needed to be converted to additional free space before adding all the free space back to the APFS container.

Oh ok that makes sense thank you.

I added the disk0s3 partition when I installed Linux, and disk0s3 needed to be deleted before adding the free space to disk0s2.
Commands:
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0

